# a RIGHT JOIN is not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

**Question UPDATED:**
Yes I know the tables are not normalized and yes I know there are no primary keys.

**Semester table**

```
Semester, Year, City
1|2017|Washington
2|2017|Paris
3|2017|London
1|2018|Paris
2|2018|Paris
3|2018|Paris
```

It will contain all possible semester.

**Grades table**

```
stuID,semster,year,marks,city
110,1,2018,66,Paris
110,3,2018,77,Paris
111,1,2018,56,London
```

As you can see the student does not have marks for 2nd semester but I want the NULL values in my result set against 2nd semester.

**Desired Output**

```
semester, marks
1,66
2,null
3,77
```

I tried this SQL query so far;

```
SELECT r.Semester, l.Marks
FROM Grade l
RIGHT JOIN Semester r
    ON l.semester = r.semester AND r.City = l.City
WHERE l.stuID = 110 AND r.year = 2018 AND l.City = 'Paris'
```

But it only returns this:

```
semester, marks
1,66
3,77
```

SQL is T-SQL

Answer (score 3):

In the future, please provide your sample data and DDL statements if possible, as continually updating your question with new data/table changes is time consuming for the person answering.

Your provided data doesn't quite match the expected output, so I filled in a few blanks.

This will return your exact output:

```
CREATE TABLE #Semester (
Semester TINYINT,
YEAR INT,
CITY VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO #Semester 
VALUES (1, 2017, 'Washington'), (2, 2017, 'Paris'), (3, 2017, 'London'), 
       (1, 2018, 'Paris'), (2, 2018, 'Paris'), (3, 2018, 'Paris');


CREATE TABLE #Grade (
StuID INT,
Semester TINYINT,
YEAR INT,
Marks INT,
City VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO #Grade
VALUES (110, 1, 2018, 66, 'Paris'), (110, 3, 2018, 77, 'Paris'), 
       (110, 1, 2018, 56, 'London');

--Left Join
SELECT r.Semester, l.Marks
FROM #Semester r
    LEFT JOIN #Grade l  ON l.semester = r.semester 
            AND l.year = r.year
          AND l.StuID = 110
          AND l.city = 'paris'
WHERE r.year = 2018 

--Right Join
SELECT r.Semester, l.Marks
FROM #Grade l
    RIGHT JOIN #Semester r  ON l.semester = r.semester 
            AND l.year = r.year
            AND l.StuID = 110
          AND l.City = 'paris'
WHERE r.year = 2018
```

Returns

```
Semester Marks
-------- -----------
1        66
2        NULL
3        77
```

The filter on `year` is placed in the `WHERE` clause because your result set only includes data for 2018 - it isn't a condition of joining the two tables together necessarily. For an `INNER JOIN` you could put a filter in the `WHERE` clause or the `INNER JOIN`, but usually people reserve the `JOIN` clause for comparing columns between tables, and comparing a static value for the `WHERE` clause to be more clear, much as people prefer `LEFT JOIN` over `RIGHT JOIN`.

With your addition of city, just add it to the `JOIN` clause.

Comment: To elaborate on this, the reason we prefer a `LEFT JOIN` is that it makes the intent more clear -- namely, you want all rows from [Semester] and only matching row values from [Grade].  The reason the OP's original query does not work is that the `WHERE` predicate `l.stuID=110` subverts the `RIGHT`-ness of the `JOIN` and turns it into a plain old `INNER JOIN` (implicitly).  Thus, the solution is to move that condition into the `JOIN`'s `ON` predicates.

Comment: in your answer, why is `r.year = 2018` not part of the `LEFT JOIN` predicate and instead it is in `WHERE` predicate?

Comment: @user1451111 The `r.Year` condition doesn't subvert the `RIGHT JOIN` because it's a member of the _right_ table (in your original query; left in our versions).  Saying you "prefer a `RIGHT JOIN`" makes it sound like an academic exercise, i.e. a homework problem.  And as much as we like helping, we're not here to do your homework.  ;)  Finally, as @LowlyDBA said, putting the `r.Year` condition in the `WHERE` clause makes your **intent** very clear.  Notice that's the 2nd time I've mentioned _clarity of intent_.  There's a reason for that.

Comment: There are several reasons why `LEFT` joins are preferred. Why do you insist on using a `RIGHT` join?

Comment: Incidentally there are a lot of places in my project where `RIGHT JOIN` have been used. It will be an effort to replace all those `RIGHT` joins with `'LEFT` joins and swap table aliases. Apart from that there is no specific reason and no, it is not a homework problem. I just noticed that my problem was 99% solved from the given answers but there is still some issue. I might need to update the question.

Comment: @user1451111 - If your project uses `RIGHT JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` in all the existing code, then it probably makes sense to continue to do so. It's functional - it's just not the way most of us expect to read a query. However, in your project it *is* the way you expect to read it, and changing individual queries to `LEFT JOIN` instead is more likely to cause problems than resolve them.

Comment: @user1451111 - Also, with the `City` column added to your query, you'd need to include `r.City = l.City` in the `ON` clause of the `RIGHT JOIN`, and `r.City = 'Paris'` in the `WHERE` clause. If you must check `l.City` instead of `r.City`, a check on `l.City` would have to be done in the `ON` clause. I find it helpful to think of it this way - when you include a check on an "optional" column in the `WHERE` clause, without allowing for that column to be NULL, you basically change the `RIGHT` or `LEFT` join into an `INNER JOIN`.